# Why is onStart() being called after onCreate()?

Tags: android, android-activity, design-patterns, android-source

I am learning about design patterns in Java. In Android, i read that,  `Oncreate()` is called before  `onStart()` followed by `onResume()` . Are they being called internally? Which design pattern are they using ? How are these Callback functions implemented?  Were they used observe patterns , interfaces or abstract classes?  Why `onStart()` is being called after `onCreate()` method?

I read the source code, but I don't understand. Could someone explain to me?

Why is `onStart()` being called after `onCreate()` function and in which design pattern ? Please give suggestions on how should read source code?

Comment: I read the source code .. I thought that may be onStart() is called after onCreate() in somewhere else. I checked Activity class Source code. But I didn't understand fully.

Comment: Could you please tell me... in which source file, they are calling those functions one after other ?

Comment: Read about [Interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html) .. n are you trying to achieve something here !?!

Comment: `I read the source code, But I didn't understand. ` it would take few hours, or days to do it, if sources are not clear for you. I don't think that somebody is going to spend so much time.

Comment: put: `((Object)null.toString();` into `onCreate` and start program ... you will get nice NPE ... but with stacktrace ... from the stacktrace you can get what was called first from the Android OS itself

Answer (score 3):

Its `interfaces` and all callbacks

[This is what `onStart()` looks like](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/app/Activity.java#Activity.onStart%28%29)

And you can follow [`LoaderManagerImpl mLoaderManager;`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/app/LoaderManager.java#LoaderManagerImpl)

And you will see it extends [`LoaderManager`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/app/LoaderManager.java#LoaderManager) 
which is

> Callback interface for a client to interact with the manager.

Answer (score 2):

On android documentation it is mentioned as

```
 public class Activity extends ApplicationContext {
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState);

 protected void onStart();

 protected void onRestart();

 protected void onResume();

 protected void onPause();

 protected void onStop();

 protected void onDestroy();
 }
```

Official documentation may help you out. and for your question 'Please give suggestions, How should I read source code' ? place debug point and follow the code execution part and see where debugger takes you . This is the best way to check on what step methods are being called. Debugger will take you up to inheritance tree. Hope it will help you out some how.You may refer below link as well... 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html